# Interpretation of different types of transformations on fields in the case of Poincaré group

Tags: special-relativity, symmetry, field-theory

I have problems understanding how transformations of Lorentz or Poincaré groups act on fields.

We can think about two ways of transformation of a field $\phi_r(x)$:
$$\phi_r(x) \rightarrow \phi^{'}_r(x^{'})=\phi_r(x)+\delta\phi$$

$$\phi_r(x) \rightarrow \phi^{'}_r(x)=\phi_r(x)+\delta\phi_0$$

in other words
$$\delta\phi=\phi^{'}_r(x^{'})-\phi_r(x)$$
$$\delta_0\phi=\phi^{'}_r(x)-\phi_r(x)$$

$\delta\phi$ confronts the field at a same physical point P represented by different coordinates $x$ and $x'$ in difference frame references. Instead $\delta_0\phi$ confronts a field at same coordinates and different physical points. A Poincaré transformation relates tdifferent inertial frames of reference and their coordinates and it is given by:
$$x^{\mu} \rightarrow x^{'\mu}=\Lambda^\mu_{\space\nu}x^v + \delta^{\mu}$$
this transformation acts on spacetime points and induce a transformation of fields of this type:
$$\phi_r(x) \rightarrow \phi^{'}_r(x^{'})=\phi_r(x)+\delta\phi_r(x)$$
the variation $\delta\phi_r(x)$ can be rewritten in this way
$$\delta\phi_r(x)=\phi^{'}_r(x^{'})-\phi_r(x)=(\phi^{'}_r(x^{'})-\phi_r(x^{'}))+(\phi_r(x^{'})-\phi_r(x))$$
so the variation can be seen as a sum of the variation at fixed coordinates and at fixed physical point. I am mostly confused by what the term $(\phi^{'}_r(x^{'})-\phi_r(x^{'}))$ represnts, as this is the kind of behaviour I expect from internal transformations for example a  multiplication of a field by a phase $e^{i\theta}$.

I try to interpret this last result on $\delta\phi_r(x)$ as follows:

- The second parenthesis $(\phi_r(x^{'})-\phi_r(x))$ gives information about how the fields vary along spacetime, for example moving from $x$ to $x^{'}$, as I am confronting in the same frame of reference the field in two different points (the frame is the same as neither of the field is primed).
- The first parenthesis $(\phi^{'}_r(x^{'})-\phi_r(x^{'}))$ express how the components of the field changes, for example how they are mixed under a rotation.

It seems in the end that the transformation is kind of decomposed in two terms, one that represents the changes of the field along space-time and another related to the actual transformation of the fields components buy a kind of internal trasformation.
I am not sure this interpretation is correct and I hope the problem is clear, the main question is about what this "decomposition" actually mean. Thanks for the help

EDIT: this kind of interpretation of the decomposition, if correct, should apply to all transformations of spacetime that induces a transformation of the fields, as the Poincaré was taken just as an example and isn't foundamental to the argument.